# C programming Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, printf, undefined-behavior

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a;
int *b;
int **c;
int ***d;
int ****e;
// * is the "value of operator"
// * is also called the dereferencing // operator

int main(void) {
    a = 25;
    b = &a; // & is the "address of operator" c = &b;
    d = &c;
    e = &d;

    printf("\n\n%d %d %d\n\n",*(&a),*b+**c, ***d*****e);

    return 0;
}
```

when i run it it says Segmentation fault: 11 how can i fix it and what it means?

Comment: You have made `c = &b;` as comment by mistake.

Comment: @Himanshu no, that's the  __actual__ error in OP's case.

Comment: http://ideone.com/tmLN3x

Comment: @SouravGhosh, yes you are right. but may be he did that by mistake in his original code.

Comment: @Himanshu That's a typo from OP, for sure. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think, in your code

```
  c = &b;
```

part is commented out by mistake. So, the value of `c` is `NULL` (global scope) and that is being dereferenced and used in `printf()` argument, which can  in turn invoke [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

[Segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) is one of the side effects of undefined behaviour. Basically it indicates some *memory access violation*.

FYI, `C11` standard document, chapter `6.5.3.3`,

> The unary `*` operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a function, the result is
>   a function designator; if it points to an object, the result is an lvalue designating the
>   object. If the operand has type `‘‘pointer to type’’`, the result has type `‘‘type’’`. If an
>   invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary `*` operator is
>   undefined.

and reagarding *invalid value*, from the footnote 102 in the same chapter

> Among the invalid values for dereferencing a pointer by the unary * operator are a null pointer, *[......]*

**Solution:** Uncomment that part.

Answer (score 0):

You missed

```
c = &b;
```

Without this you have `c` uninitialized and you are using it which leads to undefined behavior

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the line in comment.

```
c=&b;
```

This is the reason you are getting the segmentation fault.

For better understanding you can do like this.

```
printf("\n\n%d %d %d\n\n",*(&a),*b +**c, (***d)*(****e));
```

Answer (score 0):

the value of c is un initialised and we are trying to use reference of that variable to d, so pl. add c = &b before d = &c and this should solve your problem